# Laravel - где сохранить свои данные конфигурации

Tags: laravel, ооп

В форме добавления публикации есть список "категорий" к которым публикация относится.
Каждая "категория" характеризуется названием и url slugом
Список "категорий" короткий, всего 10 пунктов и делать модель под список категорий мне кажется странным, лишний раз лезть в БД.
С другой стороны в blade шаблонах  форм редактирования и в форм добавления хочется выводить их из массива с помощью foreach, а не писать вручную.

Где и как грамотно хранить такой массив, чтобы он был доступен ото всюду?

Comment: А задача модифицировать категории есть? Если нет - можно спокойно закинуть табличкой в config файл. Если нужно модифицировать - тогда уже база.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете поместить свой конфиг в папку `config` в корне вашего проекта, их количество не ограниченно.

использовать так:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
...
Config::get('forms.fields.default')
```

структура файла `/config/forms.php`

```
<?php
return [
    'fields' => [
        'default' => [1,2,3]
    ],
    'someFields' => [4,5,6]
];
```

Но как правильно заметил MikielD , если нужны динамические поля, то конфиг каждый раз править не лучшее решение.

Answer (score 0):

Я для промежуточных конфигов, которые редактируются часто, при этом хранят конфиденциальную информацию (всякие пароли и ключи), использую пакет [ValueStore](https://github.com/spatie/valuestore) (поддержка железобетонная, т.к spatie).

По сути, Json файлы с данными, особо ничего сложного, но при этом вполне себе адекватное решение.